# Is 'all:' is default in Eclipse makefile?

Tags: eclipse, makefile

I have c++ makefile project in Eclipse. Makefile contains lines:

```
executable:
    $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) aaa.cpp -o aaa.o
    $(COMPILER) aaa.o -o aaa.exe -ldl
```

Eclipse is not happy with executable and shows error;

```
make all 
make: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop.
```

How to tell Eclipse to use `executable` instead `all`?

Answer (score 1):

While I don't use Eclipse and couldn't tell you how to change the default build target, it may be worthwhile to have a target `all` since it's a pretty common thing to have.

Just specify `all` as the first target:

```
all: executable
```

As the first target it's also be the default target when no target is specified on the command line. Since the rule has no commands, all it does is depend on `executable` being built, effectively becoming an alias. To be extra safe, add

```
.PHONY: all
```

somewhere (or to existing `.PHONY` lines if you already have them) so that the existence of a file `all` won't prevent building.

Answer (score 0):

- Open the `Makefile` in the editor.
- Select "Outline View" (or open it using `Window -> Show View -> Outline`).
- In the outline view *right click* on "executable" and select "Add Build Target" from the drop down menu.
- Go to "Build Targets" view (or open it using `Window -> Show View -> Build Targets`).

The target should appear in that window under the project folder name. If it is not there (quirk) select and deselect the "Hide Empty Folders" icon in the top right of that window.

Then just double click on that entry to make that target. Do the same for other targets (clean etc...).