# How to setup eclipse with C for university work

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm fairly new to eclipse but have figured out how to use it with `Java`.

However, we are now moving on to C and I am having a hard time using it. I just want to use eclipse for my labs - i.e. to create / compile / test / run C exercises or tasks that have been set.

I created a new 'Labs' C project and have been creating the files `ex1.c`, `ex2.c` etc in the `src` folder. Eclipse doesn't like this due to more than one `main` across multiple files, but the files aren't related and each is supposed to have their own `main`.

Can someone advise me as to whether there is a better way to setup / organise my workspace for this labwork or alternatively how to compile / run single files at a time in eclipse?

Comment: You might want to try the CLion IDE https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/specials/clion/clion.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjw9ZDeBRD9ARIsAMbAmob1pWOsm3FvzdD_Ht69xnpiAKVVk-XMkFTsRB9aOB7kk9vwoJhEMOMaAtQdEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds&dclid=CK_PgqDdid4CFdNUGAodv5gHBg

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz: A couple of things to note about CLion: (1) it's a commercial product, although there is a way for students to [apply for a free version for school work](https://www.jetbrains.com/student/), and (2) my understanding is its project model is currently tied to using the CMake build system.

Comment: At the risk of violating SO policy's dislike of product comparisons, I'd venture to suggest that Visual Studio targetting Linux hosts is a far better dev experience than can be had using Eclipse on Linux. Last time I tried Eclipse (quite recently), I found it slow, debugging was poor, and it was a dire memory hog. I switched to VS, haven't looked back. And it's free for most uses too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Create one project per executable (the projects can be in the same workspace). This is pretty self-explanatory, but it might get annoying if you have a lot of executables. Also, if you need to share code between your executables, you'd have to create a separate project for the shared code and set up dependencies.
2. Create one project with multiple build configurations, one per executable. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19171230) for how to do that.
3. Use Eclipse for navigating and editing your code only, and build (and run/debug) your executables from the command line. This way, the organization of the Eclipse project(s) is irrelevant, and you can build from the command line however you want (at this stage, a simple Makefile is probably the easiest).

I prefer option #3, but to some extent it's a matter of taste; if you like to do everything including building from the IDE, go with #1 or #2.

**EDIT**: A simple Makefile might look like this:

```
ex1 : src/ex1.c
    gcc -o ex1 src/ex1.c

ex2 : src/ex2.c
    gcc -o ex2 src/ex2.c

...
```

put into a file named `makefile`, and you would then run `make` to build. (If you're on Windows you would write `ex1.exe` instead of just `ex1`.)

Have a look at a tutorial like [this one](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/) to understand how Makefiles work.

Comment: Apologies if a stupid question, but how would I use a simple makefile with the command line? The only way I know how to compile is using gcc and then running the compiled file.

Comment: @15150776: Makefiles are just a way to automate running the compiler commands, so you don't have to type out the entire compiler command each time. See my edit for an example.

Comment: You don't have to use the command line for this. Eclipse has a `Build Targets` *view* that you can add entries to from your `Makefile`. See this answert for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47943231/is-all-is-default-in-eclipse-makefile/47944286#47944286