# Eclipse CDT: multiple C++ files in single project

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm on Mac OS Mojave(Version 10.14), using Eclipse Photon. I have a single C++ project(which won't show up in the C++ perspective, only the Java perspective), and I'd like multiple packages/folders for various things. For example:

`- MyCPPProject
    - School
        - Lab01.cpp
        - Lab02.cpp
    - Personal
        - File01.cpp
        - File02.cpp`

All of the C++ files will have main methods(which is why I can't run them if they're in the same project). All of the files will be "simple," meaning that they will not do anything beyond competitive programming(so nothing beyond `cin`/`cout` or `scanf`).

The Internet says I need a new project for every main method. Does anyone have any ideas so that I can keep my programs in 1 project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: " I don't need an exe file or any of that, I just want to be able to run my CPP files.".  Uh - *what*???  ALSO: If your C++ project won't show in the CDT perspective ... that definitely sounds like a problem ;)  FINALLY: Rather than have "main methods in all your C++ files"... consider using a unit test framework instead.  Here's a video on using Google Test from Eclipse/CDT: https://www.linkedin.com/learning/test-driven-development-in-c-plus-plus/set-up-google-test-with-eclipse

Comment: @paulsm4 Sorry about that statement, I've removed it so it doesn't confuse others. I'm a beginner, so what I'm looking for is just something that can run my C++ files, and I'd prefer they're in one project and in Eclipse. I'll look into unit testing, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Your question seems very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52826462/how-to-setup-eclipse-with-c-for-university-work), see the answers there.

Comment: Visual studio has a 'solution'; you can group many projects with different `main`s.

Comment: Create a `Makefile` project and use your own `Makefile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The way Java works, you can have a different `static void main(String[] args)` for every Java class.  Neither C nor C++ work like that: you're limited to exactly one "main()" per .exe.
- That, in turn, means that you must define a separate project in Eclipse for each separate .exe.  That's just the way it is :)
- Eclipse, however, allows you to "group" projects into "Working Sets":

  [What is a working set and how do I use it?](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-a-working-set-and-how-do-i-use-it.html)

  So if you wanted to, you could organize your projects into "School" and "Personal", filtering out one or the other as you wish.
- Finally, there are C/C++ "Online Fiddles" that allow you to easily run small, standalone .cpp files and that you might prefer over Eclipse, MSVS or CodeBlocks:

  [List of Online C++ Compilers](https://arnemertz.github.io/online-compilers/)

'Hope that helps!